# How to compile Solidity code using node file system?

Tags: javascript, solidity

I'm struggling to compile my Solidity code into a build folder. I'm using node's file system to do this but I'm missing something. At the moment I'm getting this error:

```
fs.js:663
  return binding.open(pathModule.toNamespacedPath(path),
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Gary/Desktop/charity/ethereum/build/Charity.json'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:663:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1314:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Gary/Desktop/charity/ethereum/compile.js:37:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
```

I attempted to follow the example here:

[How to compile solidity using solc 0.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412333/how-to-compile-solidity-using-solc-0-5)

my compile.js file looks like this

```
    const path = require('path');
    const solc = require('solc');
    const fs = require('fs-extra');

     const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
     fs.removeSync(buildPath);

    const charityPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Charity.sol');
    const source = fs.readFileSync(charityPath, 'utf8');

    var input = {
        language: 'Solidity',
        sources: {
            'Charity.sol': {
                 content: source
            }
        },
        settings: {
            outputSelection: {
                '*': {
                    '*': [ '*' ]
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

    if(output.errors) {
        output.errors.forEach(err => {
            console.log(err.formattedMessage);
        });
    } else {
        const contracts = output.contracts["Charity.sol"];
        for (let contractName in contracts) {
            const contract = contracts[contractName];
            fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`), JSON.stringify(contract.abi, null, 2), 'utf8');
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting to destroy and update the `build` folder every time I compile. `build` folder will go into the `ethereum` folder. From there I'm expecting to compile the Solidity code from `Charity.sol` and deposit it in JSON format as a file in the `build` folder.

Instead I'm getting the above error. I believe this is a mistake due to a fundamental misunderstanding of the file system. However, I appreciate anyone who would take the time to look this over. I can provide more information upon request.

Comment: I think the issue is that you've failed to create the build directory. Probably `fs.mkdirSync(buildPath)` before the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you for helping.