# SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 (Ropsten Testnet)

Tags: javascript, ethereum

I am getting this error while deploy the code on Ropsten Testnet

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

deploy.js:

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const { interface, bytecode } = require("./compile.js");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider (
    "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/b2e9ef3a616c45f3b8b9a64ed3714848"
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async ()=> {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
    console.log("Contract is deployed by the manager with address: ", accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({data: "0x" + bytecode})
        .send({gas: "2000000", from: accounts[0]})

        console.log("Contract deployed to address", result.options.address);
}

deploy();
```

Here is the compile.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const solc = require('solc');

const helloPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Lottery.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(helloPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Lottery.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}; 

module.exports = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
```

Don't know how to solve this problem
Please Help how to solve this

**Thanks & Regards!**

Comment: Well what is the value of `interface`? I bet it's `undefined`

Comment: should I send you compile.js file?

Comment: I have added compile.js in my question you can see what's wrong in code

Comment: Again, I expect that whatever that weird code is doing will result in `interface` being `undefined`. I don't know what "solc" is, so I don't know what `solc.compile()` does or what its output looks like. Try doing some debugging on your own, to log what the various values involved actually look like.

Comment: it's just compiling the code of solidity file of lottery

Comment: Yes, but clearly *it does not work.*  You have to gain visibility into what those values actually look like.

Comment: which JSON is causing the issue? Also, I suspect that new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface)) doesn't need the JSON.parse(). If I'm not mistaked the interface you get from Solc is already good to go.

Comment: JSON.parse(interface) of deploy.js is causing the issue.
What should I do now?

Comment: The compile.js returns the wrong  format look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412333/how-to-compile-solidity-using-solc-0-5.